# Writing a regular expression for validating a string

Tags: regex, validation

I'm looking for a regular expression that validates a string that conforms to
the following rules:

1. The string must be between 1 and 11 characters in length, inclusive.
2. The first characters must be a letter (`[A-Za-z]`).
3. The last character must a letter or digit (`[A-Za-z0-9`])
4. The intermediate characters must be a word character (`\w`).
5. For a string of 1 character, rule 2 prevails.

Here are some simple test cases:

```
01: Valid
02: JustValid01
03: Valid1
04: V
05: V1
06: Invalid_
07: ToooooooLong
08: _Invalid
09: 1Invalid
10: 1
11: _
```

Case 01 to 05 should match, while 06 to 11 should not.

So far I have come up with:

```
^[A-Za-z]\w{0,9}[\w^_]?$
```

This passes all of the test cases, except for 06. What regular expression
do I need to pass all of the test cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing this, I figured out the correct regular expression:

```
^[A-Za-z](\w{0,9}[A-Za-z0-9])?$
```